# How to sort SVN LS -R output by date

Tags: sorting, date, svn, ls

I want to list all the files in my svn, sorted by date of last commit. `svn ls -Rv` lists all the files, but it doesn't accept a `-t` switch. Does anyone know how to do this?

(I have seen an answer to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22235391/svn-status-show-files-in-descending-order-date-modified) for `svn status`, but it wasn't obvious to me how to change this to work with `svn ls`.)

STILL UNANSWERED: It would also be helpful to be able to sort the files by date added to SVN.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On my Windoz box the below does the job

```
svn ls -Rv | sort
```

For Unix you will, most likely, have to specify the numeric sort order with the switch "-n"

Comment: Worked like a charm on my Linux distro too, no `-n` switch needed :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`svn list --xml`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.list.html) and sort by `<date>2014-08-20T12:34:46.712712Z</date>`.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this challenge today.  The other options didn't work for me.  I came up with a short Perl script that does the job.  It might be possible to bastardize this into a one-liner but I didn't feel like it.

Put the code into svn-sort.pl.  Command line would look something like this:

`svn ls $url | perl svn-sort.pl | sort`

I hope this helps.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;


# Main entry point.
sub main {
        my $input;

        # Read into string instead of array.
        {
                local $/ = undef;
                $input = <>;
        }


        my $count = 0;
        my $limit = 0;

        my @matches;
        while ($input =~ m|<entry.+?<name>([^<]+?)</name>.*?<date>([^<]+?)</date>.*?</entry>|gs) {
                push @matches, [$1, $2];
        }

        foreach my $m (@matches) {
                print "$m->[1]\t$m->[0]\n";

                if ($limit > 0 && ++$count > $limit) {
                        last;
                }
        }
}


# Go.
&main(@ARGV);
```