# how can i list svn folders with the logged in user credential in jenkins for build parameters?

Tags: svn, jenkins

I am trying to set up jenkins for our build environment work with subversion. I want to list subversion folder list with current user's credential for a build parameter. I googled a lot for this but i cant find a way to list the svn folders with the logged in user credentail from jenkins ? I used List Subversion Tags , ExtendedChoice parameter and  lots of plug-ins to do this. Is there any way to use currently logged in user's credential to connect to subversion while collecting the build parameters ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The groovy script below solve the issue. The script can be used with any of groovy supported parameter plugin.

```
def user = hudson.model.User.current();
def a = jenkins.model.Jenkins.getAuthentication()
def userId = user.getId() 
def pass =a.getCredentials()
def svnurl = 'http://yoursvnurl'
def dirs = [] 
def command = ['svn', 'list', svnurl , '--username' , userId , '--password' , pass ]
def proc = command.execute()
print command
proc.in.eachLine {dirs.add(it) }
return dirs
```

Comment: Thank you. It is working like a charm. But I need to show the folders in SVN from newest to oldest. How to achieve it?

Comment: check out this topic. hope may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25426001/how-to-sort-svn-ls-r-output-by-date

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it is showing the full log details in ascending order. But I need from newest to oldest plus need to show only the folders name in combo box.

Comment: if u mean most recently updated folder from "newest" this should do the trick.   

svn list -v http://svn/folder | sort -k1 -r | awk '{print $NF }'

Comment: Thank you. But, since 'awk' is s linux/unix command, it is not working in windows. The error ''awk' is not recognized as an internal or external command,' is shown while I am trying in command prompt.

Comment: linux is best for server environment but if u have to use windows try cygwin. https://cygwin.com/