# How to use environment variable in "List Subversion tags (and more)" parameter in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I am using Jenkins to automate our build and release process. 
In that I am using "List Subversion tags (and more)" parameter and hardcoded my project SVN URL in the "Repository URL" filed (Refer below Screentshot). That lists the branches of my project.

[image]

In that repository URL field, the host name of the server "svnserver" may be changed in future and it is used in 400+ jobs in Jenkins. Hence, I have created a enivironment variable in Jenkins configuration page and used in the field as follows.

[image]

But it is not working. Thats, the branches are not listed in the parameter as follows.

[image]

How to use environment variable in "List Subversion tags (and more)" parameter in Jenkins?

Comment: I am not sure but don't think so such use case is covered in the List Subversion Tags plugin. The variable replacement is usually used while checking out the repo and is working fine. Since SVN is not used much I would recommend to write a system groovy script to update the svn url across all the jobs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't think that the system groovy script will work for this scenario.

Comment: It is possible I have updated String parameter using system groovy. You need to create objects in the jenkins. Get all the job name, check if the job has List Subversion plugin enabled. get the value and update the value. Although it sounds easy but it is not.  Another approach is to update the xml in the backend and do reload of the configuration of the respective jobs -- not recommended.

Comment: I have achieved the same using 'Active Choive Reactive Parameter' and Groovy script. Referred URL : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35917742/how-can-i-list-svn-folders-with-the-logged-in-user-credentail-in-jenkins-for-bui

Comment: Yes, the groovy script is a system groovy script...that is what I suggested earlier.

Comment: @error404 Yes. Thank you. But the drawback is, the newset dir in svn cannot be listed using the above method. Working on that.